# Printing 2048 board in python with spacing with standard libraries

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing, 2048

I want to print a 2048 board with proper spacing.

I was able to reach till here.

```
╔═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╗
║ 1 │ 2 │ 3 │ 4 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 3 │ 2 │ 4 │ 5 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 1 │ 1 │ 4 │ 2 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 6 │ 5 │ 4 │ 3 ║
╚═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╝
```

But when I give larger numbers, it does not look good.

```
╔═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╗
║ 1 │ 1256 │ 3 │ 4 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 3 │ 2 │ 4 │ 123 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 1 │ 1 │ 4 │ 2 ║
╟───┼───┼───┼───╢
║ 6 │ 2048 │ 4 │ 3 ║
╚═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╝
```

How can I achieve this with only standard libraries?

Thanks!

### Edit

I know that we can use `prettytable` but I also want to print it colorful. So I cant use `prettytable`.

### Edit 2

My code -

```
print('\n'.join([
            '╔═══╤═══╤═══╤═══╗',
            '║ {} │ {} │ {} │ {} ║'.format(*board[0]),
            '╟───┼───┼───┼───╢',
            '║ {} │ {} │ {} │ {} ║'.format(*board[1]),
            '╟───┼───┼───┼───╢',
            '║ {} │ {} │ {} │ {} ║'.format(*board[2]),
            '╟───┼───┼───┼───╢',
            '║ {} │ {} │ {} │ {} ║'.format(*board[3]),
            '╚═══╧═══╧═══╧═══╝'
]))
```

Comment: what is your code so far ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can achieve this in such a simple way. My guess would be to :

- Find out the length of the biggest number in your table
- Fill out every other number with enough space to reach the same length (you can look at https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust for that)
- Generate your table with the right size